# Using Selenium C# DevTools how to capture f12 options (Network) with c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, devtools

Capture F12 options using Selenium C# DevTools, need help on C# SELENIUM, Attached snapshot

Using Selenium C#, collect logs from F12 options on any website,

For example open google.com in chrome and press F12, right side you will see developer options, capture those network logs using selenium C#. Attached snapshot what to capture[image: F12 options capture network logs]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to access the Network tab. Below code block the css/jpg/png image on the website, you can use any Network method to collect logs or implement according to the requirement.

```
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

        IDevTools devTools = iConstants.chromeDriver as IDevTools;
        IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();


        var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
        await domains.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
        await domains.Network.SetBlockedURLs(new DevTools.Network.SetBlockedURLsCommandSettings()
        {
            Urls = new string[] { "*://*/*.css", "*://*/*.jpg", "*://*/*.png" }
        });
        chromeDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        chromeDriver.Url = "https://google.com";
```